# How to redirect any subdomain to main domain on shared host?

Tags: httpd, subdomain, 301-redirect, shared-hosting

On VPS, it seems I can use `<VirtualHost>` to redirect any subdomain to main domain. On shared host, since I cannot edit the apache configuration file, how can I do?

Currently, I create a CNAME record for *.mydmain.com to redirect to mydomain.com. But When I visit nonexist.mydomain.com, it lands on nonexist.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally need to do this with the control panel level. For example Cpanel, DirectAdmin, etc.

Refers to the user manual for them and/or contact your Shared Hosting Provider. As it's a function concern, it's industry standard to include this as part of the contract for the service.

Comment: I am using CPanel. Can you please tell me which function in CPanel I can use to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Most certainly! Their Redirection would most likely be of use as explained in https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/redirects/ . Hope that helps!